# I can't make the nav bar and search bar shrink with the browser for bootstrap react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My main goal is to shrink the search bar when the browser shrinks.Theirs something wrong with how I implemented my styling, because it doesn't shrink. It still goes out the page whenever I try it.

```
return (
  <div className="Header">
    <div>
      <Navbar className="page-head container-fluid">
        <div className="logo">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/" className="text-light">
            <i className="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> Get C's
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </div>
        <Navbar.Toggle
          aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"
          className="text-light"
        />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <NavDropdown
              title={this.state.categories}
              id="collasible-nav-dropdown"
              style={{ marginLeft: "14%" }}
            >
              <NavDropdown.Item
                onClick={() => this.setState({ categories: "All" })}
              >
                All
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item
                onClick={() => this.setState({ categories: "Appliances" })}
              >
                Appliances
              </NavDropdown.Item>

              <NavDropdown.Item
                onClick={() => this.setState({ categories: "Books" })}
              >
                Books
              </NavDropdown.Item>

              <NavDropdown.Item
                onClick={() =>
                  this.setState({ categories: "Clothes&Shoes" })
                }
              >
                Clothing & Shoes
              </NavDropdown.Item>

              <NavDropdown.Item
                onClick={() => this.setState({ categories: "Electronics" })}
              >
                Electronics
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item
                onClick={() => this.setState({ categories: "Services" })}
              >
                Services
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
            <Form
              className="page-head search-form "
              // inline
              // style={{ margin: "auto" }}
              onSubmit={this.onSearch}
            >
              <FormControl
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search..."
                className=" mr-sm-2 search-box"
                // style={{ margin: "auto", width: "90%" }}
                onChange={e => {
                  this.setState({ queries: e.target.value });
                }}
              />
              <Button variant="outline-info search-button" type="submit">
                <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

CSS I implemented so far is this. I tried using flex-grow, but that had no effect. My biggest problem is also the width, I can't seem to get that working right. The navbar doesn't cover the entire width of the browser.

```
    :root {
  --primary-color: #343a40;
}

/* Reset */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Navbar */
nav {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: gray;
}
/* Navbar header */
.page-head {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.log {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
/* Search bar */
.search-form {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  width: 80rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 18rem;
}

.search-box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4rem;
}
.search-button {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working example using [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: Okay I'm loading it up here https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-flower-wfwsy

Comment: I've deleted the drop down bar, because it won't compile on codesand, but the problem isn't with that I'm stuck on having that navbar displaying correctly

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Codesandbox and while Bootstrap was not loading, after adding a CDN reference for it, with the following small changes the Navbar started working.

- Update Navbar className="page-head container-fluid" to: Navbar bg="light" expand="lg"
  // you could of course use:  xs,sm,md, lg depending on when you want the Navbar to expand..

Now optional you could  and following  before Navbar and associated divs at teh bottom to account for any erroneous styling in those tags but those changes would be optional changes depending on overall site/design requirements.

Comment: That sort of works, but I don't want the search bar to disappear. Like amazon search bar, I want to to shrink as the browser shrinks

Comment: For that you can move Search out of NavBar.Collapse and into just a NavBar and place rest of your Navigation in the NavBar.Collapse

Comment: Last dumb question, if i want the "All" to stay with the searchbar how do I go about that? ("All" has its own drop down like amazon categories)

Comment: Everything could get a separate Navbar or it you want it to display next to Search it could go in the same Navbar just all depends on where on screen you want it to display on screen.